# My program is breaking out of the first for loop after one iteration

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

Here is my code. It asks user for terms and definitions, then quizzes the user. (It tells the user the term, and the user types in the answer.) The program uses arrays to store the terms and definitions. If the user doesn't get the definition correct, the program asks the user whether they want to study it again. If so, they will type in yes, and the program will store it on a separate array. After the program quizzes the users on all the terms and definitions, round 2 starts, where the program will quiz the user only on the starred definition. The problem is, the code is only running the for loop (that quizzes the user on round 1) once, and then skips onto round 2. Why is that so? I already tried looking at other people's questions and answers, but I can't seem to find the problem in my code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ptcreate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String term;
        String definition;
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many terms would you like to study?");
        int number_terms = userInput.nextInt();
        String[] term_array = new String[number_terms];
        String[] def_array = new String[number_terms];
        String[] star_array = new String[number_terms];
        String[] stardef_array = new String[number_terms];
        System.out.println("Now, enter the " + number_terms + " terms now.");
        for (int i = 0; i < number_terms; i++) {
            term_array[i] = userInput.next();
        }
        System.out.println(
                "Now, enter all the definitions, in the correct order such that it matches the order of the terms you entered.");
        for (int i = 0; i < number_terms; i++) {
            def_array[i] = userInput.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Ok. Now for the testing!");
        for (int i = 0; i <= number_terms; i++) { // the for loop that isn't
                                                  // working.
            System.out.println("What is definition " + (i + 1));
            String answer = userInput.next();
            if (answer.equals(def_array[i])) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                star_array[i] = "null";
                stardef_array[i] = "null";
            } else if (!answer.equals(def_array[i])) {
                do {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect.");
                    System.out.println("Would you like to study this term again? Type y or n.");
                    String bool = userInput.next();
                    if (bool.equals("y")) {
                        star_array[i] = term_array[i];
                        stardef_array[i] = def_array[i];
                    } else if (bool.equals("n")) {
                        star_array[i] = "null";
                        stardef_array[i] = "null";
                    }
                    System.out.println("What is the definition " + (i + 1));
                    answer = userInput.next();
                } while (!answer.equals(def_array[i]));
                if (answer.equals(def_array[i])) {
                    System.out.println(
                            "Correct"); /*
                                         * when the user finally enters the
                                         * right definition, the program skips
                                         * to the code below
                                         */
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Now, time for testing definitions you starred!");
            for (int z = 0; z < number_terms; z++) {
                if (star_array[z].equals("null")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("What is the definition of " + star_array[z] + " ?");
                    String star_answer = userInput.next();
                    if (star_answer.equals(stardef_array[z])) {
                        System.out.println("Correct.");
                    } else if (!star_answer.equals(stardef_array[z])) {
                        do {
                            System.out.println("Incorrect. Please try again.");
                            System.out.println("What is the definition of " + star_array[z] + " ?");
                            star_answer = userInput.next();
                        } while (!star_answer.equals(stardef_array[z]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: please read about java naming conventions. You dont use _ within normal variable names!

Comment: Maybe also change `for (int i = 0; i <= number_terms; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < number_terms; i++)`, `<=` to `<`?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mcve]. There is no way all this is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= number_terms; i++)
```

You have number_terms + 1 iterations. Replace with

```
for (int i = 0; i < number_terms; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug is that the for-loop that you have tagged with the comment "the for loop that isn't working" is not looping through all the definitions. This for-loop after handling the first definition it moves on to handling round 2 instead of continuing the loop to the 2nd definition and so on. The fix requires that you place the closing bracket of this for-loop before the print statement "Now, time for testing definitions you starred!" as shown below. I have added the comment "end for-loop to ensure looping of all definitions" at the for-loop closing bracket that I have moved up in the code below. In addition this for loop's iteration condition should be 'i < number_terms' as the previous posters have indicated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ptcreate {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String term;
    String definition;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many terms would you like to study?");
    int number_terms = userInput.nextInt();
    String[] term_array = new String[number_terms];
    String[] def_array = new String[number_terms];
    String[] star_array = new String[number_terms];
    String[] stardef_array = new String[number_terms];
    System.out.println("Now, enter the " + number_terms + " terms now.");
    for (int i = 0; i < number_terms; i++) {
        term_array[i] = userInput.next();
    }
    System.out.println(
            "Now, enter all the definitions, in the correct order such " +
            "that it matches the order of the terms you entered.");
    for (int i = 0; i < number_terms; i++) {
        def_array[i] = userInput.next();
    }
    System.out.println("Ok. Now for the testing!");
    for (int i = 0; i < number_terms; i++) { // the for loop that isn't
                                              // working.
        System.out.println("What is definition " + (i + 1));
        String answer = userInput.next();
        if (answer.equals(def_array[i])) {
            System.out.println("Correct");
            star_array[i] = "null";
            stardef_array[i] = "null";
        } else if (!answer.equals(def_array[i])) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Incorrect.");
                System.out.println("Would you like to study this term again? Type y or n.");
                String bool = userInput.next();
                if (bool.equals("y")) {
                    star_array[i] = term_array[i];
                    stardef_array[i] = def_array[i];
                } else if (bool.equals("n")) {
                    star_array[i] = "null";
                    stardef_array[i] = "null";
                }
                System.out.println("What is the definition " + (i + 1));
                answer = userInput.next();
            } while (!answer.equals(def_array[i]));
            if (answer.equals(def_array[i])) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Correct"); /*
                                     * when the user finally enters the
                                     * right definition, the program skips
                                     * to the code below
                                     */
            }
        }
    } // end for-loop to ensure looping of all definitions
        System.out.println("Now, time for testing definitions you starred!");
        for (int z = 0; z < number_terms; z++) {
            if (star_array[z].equals("null")) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("What is the definition of " + star_array[z] + " ?");
                String star_answer = userInput.next();
                if (star_answer.equals(stardef_array[z])) {
                    System.out.println("Correct.");
                } else if (!star_answer.equals(stardef_array[z])) {
                    do {
                        System.out.println("Incorrect. Please try again.");
                        System.out.println("What is the definition of " + star_array[z] + " ?");
                        star_answer = userInput.next();
                    } while (!star_answer.equals(stardef_array[z]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```